# How to reset squad points?

Tags: mass-effect, windows

I am in my first play through of *Mass Effect*. I had set my squad to auto level up. But I am at the mission to retrieve Wrex's family armor. There is a box that says Decryption too low. I have Tali and Garrus with me.

I am playing on PC and the good button says reset talent points under Squad screen. But clicking on it does nothing. No way to reset their points.

Is there any way to reset their (Squad) points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to respec or adjust your point expenditures in general. The reset button would be more accurately called an **Undo** button. It only works on points you've allocated since opening the squad screen. Once you close the menu, your selections are locked in.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, in new game+ you can respec everyone when they join your squad. Simply go to the character screen and then allocate them again and you have a new build for your characters (note that it is permanent for that playthough once you confirm).